# Question about mean hitting times

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

A homogeneous Markov chain $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with discrete state space $\mathcal{S}$.

Set
$$\tau_{k}:=\text{inf} \left\{n\ge 0:\, X_n=k  \right\}.$$
where $\tau_{k}$ is defined to be $+\infty$, when doesn't exist any $n$ such that $X_n=k$.

---

$\textbf{1}.$

Now consider the [Ehrenfest model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_model),its state space $\mathcal{S}$ is a finite
set $\left\{0,1,2,...,N\right\}$ and one-step transition matrix is

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0 & 1 & & & & & \\
\frac{1}{N} & 0 & \frac{N-1}{N} & & & & \\
& \frac{2}{N} & 0 & \ddots & & & \\
& & \frac{3}{N} & \ddots & \ddots & & \\
& & & \ddots & 0 & \frac{2}{N} & \\
& & & & \frac{N-1}{N} & 0 & \frac{1}{N} \\
& & & & & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right).$$

---

From an intuitive perspective, let $T_{ij}:=\inf\left\{n\ge 0:X_{n}=j,X_{0}=i\right\}$,$i<j$,be the hitting time of reaching $j$ starting
from $i$.Since $T_{i,N}=\sum_{k=i}^{N-1}T_{k,k+1},$

then
$${\color{Red} {\text{ for any } i<N,\mathbb{E}(\tau_{N}\mid X_{0}=i)=\mathbb{E}(\tau_{i+1}\mid X_{0}=i)+\mathbb{E}(\tau_{i+2}\mid X_{0}=i+1)+\cdots+\mathbb{E}(\tau_{N}\mid X_0=N-1).（*）}}\quad$$
But how can it be proven rigorously?

By linearity of expectation,we have

$$\begin{align}
   \mathbb{E}\left[\tau_{N}\mid X_{0}=i\right]&=\mathbb{E}\left[\tau_{i+1}+\sum_{t=i}^{N-2}(\tau_{t+2}-\tau_{t+1})\mid X_{0}=i\right] \\
    &=\mathbb{E}\left(\tau_{i+1}\mid X_{0}=i\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(\tau_{i+2}-\tau_{i+1}\mid X_{0}=i\right)+\\&\cdots+\mathbb{E}\left(\tau_{N}-\tau_{N-1}\mid X_0=i\right).
\end{align}$$

How to prove that formally

\begin{align}
    &\mathbb{E}\left(\tau_{i+2}-\tau_{i+1}\mid 
 X_{0}=i\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\tau_{i+2}\mid 
 X_{0}=i+1\right);\\
     &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\cdots\cdots \\
    &\mathbb{E}\left(\tau_{N}-\tau_{N-1}\mid X_0=i\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\tau_{N}\mid X_0=N-1\right)
.\end{align}

$\textbf{2}.$

Does this conclusion $(*)$ still hold in general homogeneous Markov chain $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with discrete state space $\mathcal{S}$?

A modest attempt on $\textbf{2}$：

Let the state space $\mathcal{S}$ is
$\left\{0,1,2\right\}$ and one-step transition matrix is

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
 1/3&  1/3&  1/3\\
 0&  1/2&  1/2\\
 0&  0&  1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I find that $$\mathbb{E}\left(\tau_{2}\mid X_{0}=0\right){\color{Red} \ne }\mathbb{E}\left(\tau_{1}\mid X_{0}=0\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(\tau_{2}\mid X_{0}=1\right).$$

---

Any help will be greatly appreciated！